# SQl query Join and set duplicate column value in to null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want when join 2 table in sql query then in result
duplicate column cell One of the duplicate entries become to null.
My first table is:

```
id  corp_code   pay_authority_no    authority_price status
1    C286           210995              85020000    True
2    C286           210879              61040000    True
3    C139           212475              77708280    True
4    C139           212465              77878320    True
5    C296           216177              101335000   True
13   C321           214526              56680000    True
```

and second table is:

```
id  pay_authority_no    order_kind  order_no
2         210879         Reorder    84182
1         210995         Reorder    83251
4         212465         Sup        459950
3         212475         Sup        459948
15        212475         Sup        65878
13        214526         Reorder    86019
14        214526         Reorder    86020
5         216177         Reorder    83715
```

and also result is:

```
corp_code   pay_authority_no    authority_price order_no    order_kind
   C139           212465           77878320      459950      Sup
   C139           212475           77708280      459948      Sup
   C139           212475           77708280      65878       Sup
   C286           210879           61040000      84182       Reorder
   C286           210995           85020000      83251       Reorder
   C296           216177           101335000     83715       Reorder
   C321           214526           56680000      86019       Reorder
   C321           214526           56680000      86020       Reorder
```

i want result looks like this:

```
corp_code   pay_authority_no  authority_price   order_no    order_kind
    C139         212465         77878320         459950      Sup
    C139         212475         77708280         459948      Sup
    C139         212475         Null or 0        65878       Sup
    C286         210879         61040000         84182       Reorder
    C286         210995         85020000         83251       Reorder
    C296         216177         101335000        83715       Reorder
    C321         214526         56680000         86019       Reorder
    C321         214526         Null or 0        86020       Reorder
```

please resolve this!!

Comment: always tag the version of sql server

Comment: You could use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY authority_price ORDER BY whatever...)` then a CASE statement like `CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN authority_price END` instead of selecting authority_price.

Comment: i want this result use in to stimulreports.net , but when stimulsoft reports.net designer process duplicate set to merge then total is not true. For this reason, one must sum to zero duplicate am to correctly calculate the total amount

Comment: My sql server version is 2016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t1.corp_code, t1.pay_authority_no, 
       CASE 
          WHEN t2.rn = 1 THEN t1.authority_price
          ELSE NULL
      END authority_price,
      t2.order_no, t2.order_kind
FROM tab1 AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT order_kind, order_no, pay_authority_no,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pay_authority_no ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM tab2
) AS t2 ON t1.pay_authority_no = t2.pay_authority_no
ORDER BY t1.corp_code,t1.pay_authority_no
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this,

```
;WITH cte AS(
                SELECT t1.corp_code,t1.pay_authority_no,t1.authority_price,
                       t2.order_no,t2.order_kind,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY authority_price ORDER BY corp_code) ROWN
                FROM   tab1 t1
                       INNER JOIN tab2 t2 ON  t2.pay_authority_no = t1.pay_authority_no )

SELECT corp_code,pay_authority_no,
        CASE 
            WHEN ROWN = 1 THEN authority_price 
            ELSE NULL
        END authority_price,
       order_no,order_kind
FROM   cte
ORDER BY corp_code,pay_authority_no
```

<kbd>**[`Live Demo`](http://rextester.com/LFAA52415)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

use normalisation
this techniques remove duplicate entry in a database